# Articles on (Strongly Regular) Graphs and Covering Arrays / Covering Designs?

Tags: graph-theory, strongly-regular-graph

In their book "Algebraic Graph Theory" Godsil and Royle mention the connection of strongly regular graphs with latin squares and thus Orthogonal Arrays (Chapter 10.4). There seems not to be much research papers out there (my Google search was not very successful). Where can I find more papers on that topic ?

I would be particularly interested in connections of so called Covering Arrays (CAs) with graphs (strongly regular or not).  CAs are the somewhat relaxed form of OAs. For information on Covering Arrays see e.g. http://math.nist.gov/coveringarrays/coveringarray.html or a Google search "covering arrays".

I am wondering, if graph theory can help in the research of CAs, which are connected with software testing.
Is there any known connection of CAs with graphs ? Research papers ? Even books ? (I am NOT searching how to derive CAs from graph representations of software programs (so called model based test suite generation).).

**Edit**: I **did** find a bunch of interesting papers (e.g. [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jcd.20288/abstract;jsessionid=7BD9B8E9E4F62325F16A9DB6EDC94914.f02t03)) by Karen Meagher (University of Regina in Canada) and co-workers, but their reaearch on that topic seems to be on halt currently.

Comment: Peter Cameron discusses the connection between strongly regular graphs, latin squares and orthogonal arrays here: http://designtheory.org/library/encyc/topics/lsee.pdf

Comment: @Nick Gill Thanks for the helpful hint !

Comment: I found this, which is exactly in the direction I need: "Covering arrays avoiding edeges" by Peter Danziger, Eric Mendelsohn, Laura Moura, and Bret Stevens, in Theoretical Computer Science, 410 (2009) 5403-5414